# Passing argument to prestart npm-script

Tags: npm, gulp, webpack

package.json

```
    {
        ..
        "scripts": {
              "prestart": "gulp",
              "start": "webpack-dev-server"
        },
        ..
    }
```

i need to pass appname to both gulp as well as webpack-dev-server.

When i am  doing `npm start -- --app=todo`

the argument --app=todo is only available to webpack-dev-server not in gulp.

Any solution to pass argument to both the task.

I tried `"scripts" : {"start" : "gulp & webpack-dev-server"}` as well.

Comment: How do you launch `prestart`?

Comment: npm-scripts provide hooks for prestart. Whenever we run start, npm internally call prestart, then start, then poststart.https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts follow this for more information.

Comment: Did you try to create a bash script for that ?

Comment: i know i have that solution.. but i want a alternate solution.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question and came upon [this conversation](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/6343).  It appears that this is deliberately not possible.